# How to force gradle continue build on failure of a test suite with junit 4 and junit 5

Tags: gradle, junit, junit4, junit5

I have a project, with tests implemented by junit 4 and 5. Some of the tests require a database to be present, is there any way I can mark these specific tests (is TestSuite the answer?), so gradle continue the build even if those tests fail?

I don't want to skip other tests, but just these specific tests.

And I am using junit 5 vintage, so my test task runs both junit 4 and junit 5 tests together.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I wouldn't do this. What is the point of a test if you ignore it when it fails? You might as well delete the test right away. Can't you delay test execution if setup is slow?

That said...

`gradle --continue` will [continue execution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continue_build_on_failure) when a task fails, collecting all the errors. You may still need to ignore Gradle's exit code (e.g., in a build pipeline).

You can also use the [ignoreFailures](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures) test property to always ignore failing tests.

Both may be a bit too broad. Depending on your build script, you could add have a separate test target for database tests and add `ignoreFailures` only to that.

If you want to handle this in JUnit, you could look into [the Assume class](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-conditional-assume) which lets you skip a test if a certain condition is (or is not) given:

```java
import static org.junit.Assume.*;

public class SomeDatabaseTest {
    @Test
    public void someThing() {
        assumeTrue(Database.isAvailable());
        // actual test goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: well there are 2 sites which I run the tests on... one with that Oracle and one without it... I test other scenarios with H2 database... but there are some specific Oracle tests...

Comment: „What is the point of a test if you ignore it when it fails?“ — Maybe there are more errors at later steps of the build and I want to work on those later errors first. — Maybe I want to work in the error next week — Maybe I want to know how many errors there are in total so i have an overview on how far away from finishing I am. — Many reasons why one would want to continue the build.

Comment: @Martin Exactly. For the OP's case having the DB reliably available would be better (hard with Oracle). However for the general question, being able to get a complete list of errors/ test failures is often important when undertaking larger-scale work eg. comparing branches or integrating major changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this block of code to your module or project level build.gradle file:

```
project.gradle.teskGraph.whenReady {
    connectedDebugAndroidTest {
        ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

You can use any of the test tasks instead of connectedDebugAndroidTest.  You can also specify @Test for only those tests annotated as such.  See Android documentation here for example of [tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests).